# the person has burned of fire or from fire?

Tags: prepositions

In case that someone touch the fire, what is the right sentence?

The person has burned **of** fire 
or

The person has burned **from** fire?

Comment: Neither. He ***was*** burned ***by*** fire - but normally you'd just say *He was burned*, since "fire" is contextually obvious. Unless you're referring to a *specific* fire, in which case *He was burned by **the** fire* implies he suffered burns, but possibly/probably survived. Whereas (switching to an inanimate subject to spare the squeamish) *It was burned **in** the fire* strongly implies that it was completely destroyed by the fire.

Comment: @Fumble - That's an answer, not a comment. (A pretty good answer, too, I  might add.)

Comment: @J.R.♦ There's a whole raft of additional stuff about how "burn" works - top of the list being that it covers a huge range from *temporary pain leaving no visible or permanent damage* through *extreme and permanent damage* all the way to *totally consumed by flames, leaving at most "ashes"*. I didn't want to spend that long on posting an answer.

Comment: @Fumble - Fair enough. There's also a raft of additional stuff about how "fire" works, too – how when something is burning, it's "on fire" but when it's been burned, it was burned "by fire." And maybe you couldn't invest more time in an answer because you had too many irons **in** the fire. :^)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### The person *was* burned *by* the fire.

I think that *by* is the preposition you'd usually see in this case. For example, a tragic news story used this wording:

> The Sacramento Fire Department says one of its firefighters was burned by the fire as he tried to enter the home. ([Source](http://www.capradio.org/articles/2015/12/01/2-children-killed-in-south-sacramento-house-fire))

You could also use this wording for more minor burns:

> *Her hand was burned by the fire, and we had to ice it down for almost an hour*.